# R - change value to value from preceding row if conditions are true

Tags: r, dplyr

I have got a table like this:

[image]

If populated_area in preceding row == 1 and also in current row, preceding row == 1, I'd like to change the value of the city_name to stay the same. I have tried following code:

```
df_city <- read.table(text="business_owner  city_name   populated_area
John    A   1
John    A   1
John    A   1
John    A   1
John    A   1
John    B   1
John    B   1
John    A   1
John    A   1
John    A   1
John    A   1
John    C   0
John    C   0
John    C   0
John    B   0
John    D   0
Adam    D   1
Adam    D   1
Adam    B   1
Adam    D   1
Adam    D   1
Adam    D   1",header  = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df_city <- df_city %>% 
           group_by(business_owner) %>% 
           mutate(city_name = ifelse(
             populated_area == 1 & lag(populated_area) == 1 & !is.na(lag(populated_area)),lag(city_name),city_name))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using `replace` and `fill` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_city %>%
  group_by(business_owner) %>%
  mutate(city_name = replace(city_name, populated_area == 1 & lag(populated_area) == 1, NA)) %>%
  fill(city_name) %>%
  ungroup
  

#   business_owner city_name populated_area
#1            John         A              1
#2            John         A              1
#3            John         A              1
#4            John         A              1
#5            John         A              1
#6            John         A              1
#7            John         A              1
#8            John         A              1
#9            John         A              1
#10           John         A              1
#11           John         A              1
#12           John         C              0
#13           John         C              0
#14           John         C              0
#15           John         B              0
#16           John         D              0
#17           Adam         D              1
#18           Adam         D              1
#19           Adam         D              1
#20           Adam         D              1
#21           Adam         D              1
#22           Adam         D              1
```

Turn the values to `NA` in `city_name` when the current and previous `populated_area` is 1, use `fill` to replace those `NA` values with the previous ones.